# Multi language website, ID based URLs, and SEO

Tags: seo, url, multilingual

In a multi language website, can we use different product IDs for different language versions of the site? Will it affect SEO or not? For example:

English: `www.example.com/en/personal-care/nivea-123`
Hindi: `www.example.com/hi/personal-care/nivea-345`

We will use language codes in the URL, but can we also change the product or page id along with the language? If we do, then will it create issues with Google or any other search engine?

Comment: Do you use `hreflag` to link between those URLs?

Answer (score 1):

This *shouldn't* be considered duplicate content by Google.

> Localized versions of a page are only considered duplicates if the main content of the page remains untranslated.

However providing `hreflang` is recommended.

> Use `hreflang` to tell Google about the variations of your content, so that we can understand that these pages are localized variations of the same content.

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/specialty/international/localized-versions

Comment: I agree with this answer, but I was asking about hreflang in a comment just because I think having separate IDs for the different languages is going to make it more difficult to implement it. I suspect because they have used different IDs they haven't actually implemented hreflang.